# Three dimensional array to store data from worksheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workseeht with about 20.000 cells of data. This data belong to a different sample every 200 rows. I would like to store this data into a 3 dimensional array to be able to access the data afterwards, I'd like to do something like this:

```
lastCol = 15 
n = 1

For i = 1 To 200 Step 199
    sample(n) = sheets(1).range(Cells(i, lastCol), Cells(i + 199, lastCol)).Resize(200, lastCol)
    n = n + 1
Next
```

*I know that the way I'm assigning the values is incorrect, but I haven't managed to find a clear explanation on how to do this correctly.

*To clarify this again: Im trying to store and then access a matrix that would have the following size: 10x200x15, 10 samples of 200 rows times 15 columns

Comment: Do you mean `100*200*15` as `100*200 = 20,000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (if you want exactly the structure you mentioned) would be to read the range in an array and then loop through it and put it in the desired structure, like in the following code:

```
Sub Arrays()
Dim InArr As Variant
Dim OutArr() As String
Dim R As Long, rowcount As Long, C As Integer, colcount As Integer, Samp As Long
    InArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B2000").Value2
    rowcount = UBound(InArr, 1)
    colcount = UBound(InArr, 2)
    ReDim OutArr(1 To Int((rowcount - 1) / 200) + 1, 1 To 200, 1 To colcount)
    For R = 1 To rowcount
        Samp = Int((R - 1) / 200) + 1
        For C = 1 To colcount
            OutArr(Samp, (R - 1) Mod 200 + 1, C) = InArr(R, C)
        Next C
    Next R
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A 1D array containing 200 (2D) range variables might be a better way to go about it:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    ReDim v(1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To 20000 Step 200
        If VarType(v(1)) <> vbVariant Then ReDim Preserve v(UBound(v) + 1)
        Set v(UBound(v)) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Resize(200, 15)
        Debug.Print v(UBound(v)).Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

The `Debug.Print` command produce the output below, confirming that the correct range variables are in the variant array:

```
$A$1:$O$200
$A$201:$O$400
$A$401:$O$600
...
...
$A$19401:$O$19600
$A$19601:$O$19800
$A$19801:$O$20000
```

Comment: I don't quite get some of the things in the answer you gave me, however, it does compile fine.

Im just not sure now how to access the data. Let's say, I want to access the sample "n" in row "row" and column "col" and then do some calculations with the data and write it into a cell.

I was expecting something like : sample(n, row, col) to access the data

Comment: Since `sample(n)` represents a `Range` object (which is 200 rows by 15 columns), you can access it like this: `sample(n).Cells(row,col)`